# Visual Studio 2017 keep file open by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide

I have an annoying problem with Visual Studio 2017. 
Whenever, I open a file using Ctrl+Click navigation, the the file gets opened in purple tab preview mode (for a lack of better term).

Please note: I'm not asking about Visual Studio Code, I'm asking about VS 2017. I know how to change these setting in VSCode. After googling multiple times for VS2017, I finally gave up. Maybe I didn't phrase the question correctly.

**Example shown below.**

[image]

After I click on the "Keep Open" option, the file gets added to the open set of tabs. 
**I would prefer to have this behavior by default.**

Also, it it possible to add this tab to the right of all other open tabs? Currently, it adds itself to the beginning. I prefer to append new tabs to the right/rear.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can uncheck the **Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab** option to keep files open:

[image]

And there is the **Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs** option nearby to add this tab to the right of all other open tabs.

Comment: Thank you. I scoured the settings options multiple times but couldn't find this option. You have saved me from a lot of frustration. I have accepted your answer.